# Why should eigenvectors be orthonormal if we start in an orthonormal basis?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

As part of the development of degenerate perturbation theory, I think the author uses the following fact tacitly. I'll assume we're in a finite-dimensional space for simplicity. Suppose I have an orthonormal basis $E=\{e_i\}$ and some Hermitian operator $H_1$ which is not diagonalized by $E$. When I do diagonalize $H_1$ in this basis, am I guaranteed that the basis so obtained will be orthonormal (given that I started in an orthonormal basis)? Am I guaranteed at least that they will be orthogonal (if I have degenerate eigenvalues, this is a concern).

Comment: It depends on *how* you diagonalize, which you never told us. Consider the identity map. It is Hermitian and *every* basis is a basis of eigenvectors of the identity map. So not all possible bases of eigenvectors are orthonormal or even orthogonal.

Comment: The thing is that the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal. This a property of Hermitian operators $r(u,v)=(Hu,v)=(u,Hv)=s(u,v)$, for eigenvectors $u,v$ for the eigenvalues $r,s$. You can see there, that if $r\neq s$, then $(u,v)=0$.

Comment: @NDB Yes, I agree, but I specified I worried about the degenerate eigenvalue case.

Comment: @KCd I agree, and my apologies -- I am not sure I know/knew how to specify the diagonalization algorithm. I suppose I am thinking about the usual strategy of setting up the eigenvalue equation once we've found the eigenvalues via a determinantal method, and solving by e.g. row reduction?

Comment: Within each eigenspace you can always orthogonalize its base. So, even if you didn't have one, you can produce one that is.

Comment: Ah, that’s true and fair enough. Thanks @NDB